# jQuery Scale Effect Not Working

Tags: jquery, scale

Edit: It seems like hide and show effects don't work, but other effects work fine.

I'm trying to make some graphics grow when the page load, but it's not working so far. Simply nothing happens. The thing is that other jQuery effects work just fine. I'd appreciate any help!

My html;

```
<div id="graphics">

<div id="twitter"><p>social media connected</p></div>

<div id="seo"><p>search engine optimized</p></div>

<div id="hand"><p>easy to update</p></div>

<div id="responsive"><p>responsive</p></div>

</div>
```

and my css;

```
#graphics {
margin: 170px auto 0 auto;
width:700px;
height:80px;
}

#graphics p{
margin-top:75px;
text-align:center;
font-size:1em;
}


#twitter, #seo, #hand, #responsive {
height:72px;
width:105px;
float:left;
margin-right:0px;
}


#twitter {
background-image:url(images/twitter.png);
margin-right:93px;
}

#seo {
background-image:url(images/seo.png);
margin-right:93px;
}

#hand{
background-image:url(images/hand.png);
margin-right:93px;
}

#responsive {
background-image:url(images/responsive.png);
}
```

and last, javascript code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#twitter").show( "scale", 
     {percent: 100, }, 2000 );
});
```

Comment: You have an extra comma that needs to be removed here: `{percent: 100,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `scale` requires jQuery UI.

You also have an extra `,` in your code.

I was able to get the effect working by hiding the element initially and including jQuery UI:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tJzuA/3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="twitter" style="display: none;"><p>social media connected</p></div>
```

code:

```
$("#twitter").show( "scale", {percent: 100}, 2000 );
```

Comment: display:none and removing the extra coma did the work! Thank you! Another thing, how can I make them grow from the center? Right now it grows from bottom right.

Comment: changed the css to "#twitter { background:url(images/twitter.png) no-repeat center}" and that did the trick!